# How do I implement a custom FilterSecurityInterceptor using grails 1.3.2 and the plugin spring-security-core 1?

Tags: java, grails, filter, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm writing a grails 1.3.2 application and implementing security with spring-security-core 1.0.  For reasons outside the scope of this question, I'm implementing a custom FilterSecurityInterceptor in addition to the out of the box interceptors.  I've started with a [blog entry](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/01/15/hacking-custom-authentication-providers-with-grails-spring-security.html) on the topic and attempted to adjust it for Spring Security 3 without much success.

Loosely following the blog (since it is based on an older version of Spring Security), I've created the following classes:

1. A org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken subclass to hold my credentials.
2. A org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider subclass to implement the authenticate and supports methods for populating an Authentication instance with data from my UserDetailsService.
3. A org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor subclass to  implement doFilter and afterPropertiesSet methods.
4. Some configuration of beans and the spring-security-core plugin to recognize my AuthenticationProvider and insert my filter into the filter chain.

My AbstractAuthenticationToken is pretty simple:

```
class InterchangeAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
 String credentials
 Integer name
 Integer principal

 String getCredentials() { //necessary or I get compilation error
  return credentials
 }

 Integer getPrincipal() { //necessary or I get compilation error
  return principal
 }
}
```

My AuthenticationProvider is pretty simple:

```
class InterchangeAuthenticationProvider implements org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider {

 Authentication authenticate(Authentication customAuth) {
  def authUser = AuthUser.get(customAuth.principal)
  if (authUser) {
   customAuth.setAuthorities(authUser.getAuthorities())
   customAuth.setAuthenticated(true)
   return customAuth
  } else {
   return null
  }
 }

 boolean supports(Class authentication) {
  return InterchangeAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication)
 }

}
```

I've implemented a trivial FilterSecurityInterceptor.  Eventually this will do something interesting:

```
class InterchangeFilterSecurityInterceptor extends FilterSecurityInterceptor implements InitializingBean {

 def authenticationManager
 def interchangeAuthenticationProvider
 def securityMetadataSource

 void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {

  if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
    def myAuth = new InterchangeAuthenticationToken()
    myAuth.setName(1680892)
    myAuth.setCredentials('SDYLWUYa:nobody::27858cff')
    myAuth.setPrincipal(1680892)
    myAuth = authenticationManager.authenticate(myAuth);
    if (myAuth) {
     println "Successfully Authenticated ${userId} in object ${myAuth}"

     // Store to SecurityContextHolder
     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(myAuth);
     }    
  }
  chain.doFilter(request, response)
 }

 void afterPropertiesSet() {
  def providers = authenticationManager.providers
  providers.add(interchangeAuthenticationProvider)
  authenticationManager.providers = providers
 }
}
```

Finally I configure some beans:

```
beans = {
  interchangeAuthenticationProvider(com.bc.commerce.core.InterchangeAuthenticationProvider) {
  }
  interchangeFilterSecurityInterceptor(com.bc.commerce.core.InterchangeFilterSecurityInterceptor) {
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    interchangeAuthenticationProvider = ref('interchangeAuthenticationProvider')
    securityMetadataSource = ref('objectDefinitionSource')
  }
}
```

And do some configuration of the plugin:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.dao.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = true //not setting this causes exception
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
'interchangeAuthenticationProvider',
'daoAuthenticationProvider',
'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]
```

And set the filter order in Bootstrap.groovy:

```
def init = {servletContext ->
  //insert our custom filter just after the filter security interceptor
  SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('interchangeFilterSecurityInterceptor', SecurityFilterPosition.SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER.order + 10)
  <snip />
}
```

When I hit a URL, I get the following exception which stumps me:

```
2010-07-30 15:07:16,763 [http-8080-1] ERROR [/community-services].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:171)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:67)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

So where am I messing up, or did I make this too complex and I missed something simple?

Comment: By the way, here is the line of code with the NPE: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java#171

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I implemented a custom filter, but not a FilterSecurityInterceptor.  I inserted my filter after the OOTB rememberMe filter.  Furthermore I found my authentication implementation to be somewhat resource-intensive and slow, so I made it set the rememberMe cookie on successful authentication.  On the whole, this was a painful experience so I'll make an attempt to document it here.

My filter implementation was as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisherAware
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean

class CustomRememberMeAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

    def authenticationManager
    def eventPublisher
    def customService
    def rememberMeServices
    def springSecurityService

    //make certain that we've specified our beans
    void afterPropertiesSet() {
        assert authenticationManager != null, 'authenticationManager must be specified'
        assert customService != null, 'customService must be specified'
        assert rememberMeServices != null, 'rememberMeServices must be specified'
    }

    void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res

        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {           
            Authentication auth
            try {
                auth = customService.getUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request)
                if (auth != null) {
                    springSecurityService.reauthenticate(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials())
                    logger.debug("SecurityContextHolder populated with auth: '"
                        + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() + "'")
                    onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
                } else {
                    logger.debug('customService did not return an authentication from the request')
                }
            } catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
                logger.warn("SecurityContextHolder not populated with auth, as "
                    + "springSecurityService rejected Authentication returned by customService: '"
                    + auth + "'", authenticationException)
                onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, auth)
            } catch(e) {
                logger.warn("Unsuccessful authentication in customRememberMeAuthenticationFilter", e)
                onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, auth)
            }
        } else {
            logger.debug("SecurityContextHolder not populated with auth, as it already contained: '"
                + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() + "'")
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) {
        //sets the rememberMe cookie, but cannot call "loginSuccess" because that filters out requests
        //that don't set the rememberMe cookie, like this one
        rememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(request, response, authResult)
    }

    protected void onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) {
        //clear the rememberMe cookie
        rememberMeServices.loginFail(request, response)
    }

    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher) {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher
    }
}
```

Hopefully others find this helpful when implementing their custom authentication solutions.  We found this worked for us when integrating our application with our legacy system.

Comment: I posted a somewhat more comprehensive description of the implementation here: http://cricker.tumblr.com/post/953860464/constructing-a-custom-spring-security-filter-in-grails

Answer (score 1):

Given where it's failing (fairly unrelated) I'd guess that it's the nested properties. Try

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.dao.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
    'interchangeAuthenticationProvider',
    'daoAuthenticationProvider',
    'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
    'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider'
]
```

My guess is that it's resetting the rest of the config (a Grails/ConfigSlurper quirk) and that this will merge in the properties instead. You shouldn't need to set "active = true" but I'm guessing you needed to add that since it's also getting reset.

btw - you can remove the getters from InterchangeAuthenticationToken since public fields generate getters automatically.

Comment: I tried restating config and I get the same result.

RE the getters, if I comment them out and build, then I cannot compile:

  [groovyc] /Users/calef/community-services/src/groovy/com/bc/commerce/core/InterchangeAuthenticationToken.groovy: 7: Can't have an abstract method in a non-abstract class. The class 'com.bc.commerce.core.InterchangeAuthenticationToken' must be declared abstract or the method 'java.lang.Object getCredentials()' must be implemented.
  [groovyc]  @ line 7, column 1.
  [groovyc]    class InterchangeAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {
  [groovyc]    ^

Comment: Make sure to run 'grails clean' to force a full recompile. You could also install the spring-security-ui plugin which has info pages that'll show the registered authenticators, filters, properties, etc. and you can use that to verify that things are setup as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the spring-security-core plugin because the `securityMetadataSource` isn't injected into the default spring security `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. Perhaps the plugin gets confused and injects the `securityMetadataSource` into your custom `FilterSecurityInterceptor` and neglects the other (default one)? Burt might be willing to look deeper info that.

Perhaps you could try *replacing* the default `FilterSecurityInterceptor` with your custom one using the `grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterNames` property...

Comment: I tried the approach of setting filterNames to replace FilterSecurityInterceptor, but oddly the filternames didn't change when I set the property.