# Custom Filter Interceptor and Grails spring-security 2.0rc2 plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

i'm working on a grails (2.3.5) webapp with spring security core 2.0RC2 plugin. 
I try to create a custom filter following this [custom-security-filter-for-grails-spring-security-3-plugin](http://oavatos.org/2011/03/26/custom-security-filter-for-grails-spring-security-3-plugin/), similar to this stackoverflow post [3392552](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392552/how-do-i-implement-a-custom-filtersecurityinterceptor-using-grails-1-3-2-and-the). This peace of code are working better if the version of grails spring-security plugin is 1.2.7.3, than if the version is 2.0rc2 the webapp doesn't start and the log contains this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter(SpringSecurityUtils.java:454)
at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:37)
at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I try to create a simple servlet filter but the error was the same.

thank's for replies

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug. Please create a small test app that demonstrates the problem and run "grails bug-report". Attach that generated zip to an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE and I'll take a look.

Comment: while I was preparing the testapp, I realized that it seems to work!!! After a very long debug session i found the problem: the filter interceptor doesn't work if this is set     grails.plugin.springsecurity.debug.useFilter = true
I don't know if this is bug (i opened an issue however) or not.A workaround is to not to use the debug filter and all seems to work fine.

Comment: This was a bug and has been fixed for 2.0. As you point out, the workaround until then is to not use the debug filter feature if you have custom filters.